# How can I get this C code fast than others?

Tags: c

I'm trying to solve some problems on a programming contest system and
solving a 2 points distance problem, I don't understand why my code was ranked in 1181º of all the submissions.

How Can I do my code be fast than it is?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(){
    register unsigned int x1,x2,y1,y2;
    scanf("%i %i %i %i", &x1,&y1,&x2,&y2);
    printf("%.4f", sqrt(pow(x2-x1,2) + pow(y2-y1, 2)));
}
```

Comment: Putting the variables in registers isn't all that much faster. Math functions on the other hand are very slow. And use `%u` to scan for `unsigned int`s.

Comment: [Fast Approximate Distance Functions](http://www.flipcode.com/archives/Fast_Approximate_Distance_Functions.shtml)

Comment: First of all, you probably want to get rid of `scanf`. Then, get rid of the math functions too. Then, use a [fast approximation formula](http://mathforum.org/kb/thread.jspa?threadID=48233&messageID=170470).

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_inverse_square_root as a pointer on how such things are done. Also use a tool like glowcode, or else you can't even tell if it's fast or not.

Comment: How Can I get rod of `scanf`? I don't know any replacement of it.

Comment: Try `fread` and `fputs` instead.

Comment: Here's a couple things you could try: Make a ~100 line test file and feed it through, and run a profiler on your code to see where your code is spending a lot of its time. (I use Valgrind) You could also compile to Assembly, and view that.

Comment: In strict mode, your code wouldn't compile. Taking the address of objects declared with `register` storage class isn't allowed.

Answer (score 5):

If you avoid using `pow()`, not only are you avoiding a function call that's unnecessary if you multiply (x2-x1) by itself (which may or may not get optimized out--I'm not sure), but you can delay casting to a floating-point value until there is just one, to `sqrt()`.

If your actual problem involves reading more than just one line of input (and assuming integer reads as in your example), I'd suspect the biggest difference in performance will be in ditching `scanf()` in favor a well-written custom function using, for example, `fread()` from `stdin`.

Comment: +1 - There are **many** great reasons to get rid of `scanf()` calls. Speed is but one. Where I work we've found in testing that execution time wise stream IO > scanf > itoa (we used integers, but I suspect the relationship is the same). Outside of your competition environment, you will also find that scanf is the most error-prone way to do conversions. It is debateably harder to read as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can get rid of some redundant function calls and also avoid int->float conversion:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(){
    double x1,x2,y1,y2;
    scanf("%lf %lf %lf %lf", &x1,&y1,&x2,&y2);
    printf("%.4f\n", sqrt((x2-x1)*(x2-x1)+(y2-y1)*(y2-y1)));
    return 0;
}
```